# Jquery Nested Accordion - sub accordion set certain elements expanded by default

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

I am currently working on a site using the Nested Accordion example from http://www.adipalaz.com/experiments/jquery/nested_accordion.html

I have searched for a solution on google and this site but I cannot find one, or maybe I have found a solution but I don't understand how to implement it correctly.

The accordion code I have so far is pretty much stock from the example so far. 
The current behavior is that when 'Heading 1' is clicked, both 'Heading A' and 'Heading B' in the sub accordion are closed, and need to be clicked to expand.

I am trying to change the behavior of the site so when 'Heading 1' is clicked, 'Heading A' is already expanded, but 'Heading B' is still closed in the sub accordion. I am trying to get this to apply to all of the main accordion headers.

I don't want to set 'Heading A' as the initShow value for the main accordion because I like how all of the main accordion headers are closed when the page loads.

So I tried adding an ID for the nested accordions to try and be able to set the initShow value for only the nested accordion. But I don't think I implemented it correctly because the changes didn't affect the behavior of the site.

I am not a very strong web developer and I am very new to JQuery and Javascript in general, but I am working on improving.
Can someone please point me in the right direction?

**Please see my current code here:** http://jsfiddle.net/wmnmF/

Nested Accordion Configuration:

```
    $("html").addClass("js");
                    $(function() {
                            $("#main").accordion({
                                    objID: "#asset",
                                    el: ".h",
                                    head: "h4, h5",
                                    next: "div",
                                    expandSub: true,
                                    showMethod: "show",
                                    hideMethod: "hide",
                                    //initShow : "div.shown",
                                    event: "click",
                                    standardExpansible: true
                            });

                            $("#main .accordion").expandAll({
                                    trigger: ".h",
                                    ref: "h4.h",
                                    cllpsEl: "div.outer",
                                    speed: 0,
                                    oneSwitch : false,
                                    instantHide: true
                            });

                            $("html").removeClass("js");
                    });
            </script>
```

**Thank you!**